# Rails | Too many redirects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, controller, routes

I have routes such as;

```
scope to: 'search#show' do
  get '/search/:country_id/:rental_type_id/:group_id', as: 'search_country'
  get '/search/:country_id/:city_id/:rental_type_id/:group_id', as: 'search_city'
end
```

My problem is, when there is city as well, I should redirect to `search_city_path` but both routes are handled at `search#show` action.

When I check if there is `city_id` and redirect to show action again, it start infinite redirection. How can I prevent this?

Here is my show action;

```
  def show


    @rental_type = RentalType.friendly.find(params[:rental_type_id])    
    @group = Group.friendly.find(params[:group_id])

    if !params[:boat_city_id].blank?

      @country = Country.friendly.find(params[:country_id])  
      @city = City.friendly.find(params[:city_id])

        redirect_to search_city_path(country_id: @country, city_id: @city, rental_type_id: @rental_type, group_id: @group, q: params[:q])
      else
        @country = Country.friendly.find(params[:country_id])  
    end  
....
```

**EDIT**

Show action;

```
def show


    @rental_type = RentalType.friendly.find(params[:rental_type_id])    
    @boat_group = BoatGroup.friendly.find(params[:boat_group_id])




    if !params[:new_boat_country_id].nil? && params[:new_boat_country_id] != params[:boat_country_id] 

      @country = BoatCountry.friendly.find(params[:new_boat_country_id])
      redirect_to search_country_path(boat_country_id: @country, rental_type_id: @rental_type, boat_group_id: @boat_group, q: params[:q])

    elsif !params[:boat_city_id].blank?

      @country = BoatCountry.friendly.find(params[:boat_country_id])  
      @city = BoatCity.friendly.find(params[:boat_city_id])

        render 'search_city'
      else
        @country = BoatCountry.friendly.find(params[:boat_country_id])  
    end  



    if BoatGroup.friendly.find(params[:boat_group_id]).name == 'All' 

      if params[:boat_city_id].blank?
        b = @country.boats.where("(stat = ? AND boat_category = ?)", "Approved", "list" )
      else
        @city = BoatCity.friendly.find(params[:boat_city_id])
        b = @city.boats.where("(stat = ? AND boat_category = ?)", "Approved", "list" )
      end

    else
      b = @boat_group.boats.where("(stat = ? AND boat_category = ?)", "Approved", "list" )
    end



      @q = b.ransack(params[:q])
      @boats = @q.result(distinct: true).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 15)


  end
```

Comment: Why do you want to `redirect_to search_city_path` again? Based on the existence of `params[:city_id]`, you can query and show the search results instead

Answer (score 0):

'Show' is a 'get' method and has its own views to be rendered. Using 'redirect' inside 'show' method will give you infinite redirection error. So,

```
use 'render' instead of 'redirect'
```

For eg

render search_city will render a html page named search_city.html.erb. render search_country will render a html page named search_country.html.erb.  And you can add the view you want inside the above html pages. So the code will be

```
if !params[:new_boat_country_id].nil? && params[:new_boat_country_id] != params[:boat_country_id] 

      @country = BoatCountry.friendly.find(params[:new_boat_country_id])
      render 'search_country'
    elsif !params[:boat_city_id].blank?

      @country = BoatCountry.friendly.find(params[:boat_country_id])  
      @city = BoatCity.friendly.find(params[:boat_city_id])

        render 'search_city'
      else
        @country = BoatCountry.friendly.find(params[:boat_country_id])  
    end
```

And the params like @country, @city, @rental_type, @group, params[:q] can still be accessed in the view without passing them as params as you have done in your method.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. The reason of redirection is mainly because I want 2 urls. search/country/.. and search/country/city.. But if I use render method I have to have another view (probably same with show.html.erb).

Comment: I have tried that and I have form (ransack) in that show page, I also put it to search_city.html.erb. It now gives error; No Ransack::Search object was provided to search_form_for!

Comment: Have you initialized the Ransack object in your show method in your controller?

Comment: Editing question adding whole action

Comment: in show.html.erb and search_city.html.erb I have a form starting with <%= search_form_for @q , url: search_country_path, :method => :get do |f| %> is it because of that? search_country_path is the show action

Comment: Why do you want to use 'get' method for a form. Use a post method for a form. And based on the params use the redirect in the 'post' method. 'Show' method is a 'get' method used for displaying data and not to perform form operations.

Comment: Thank you but this does not solve the error: No Ransack::Search object was provided to search_form_for! Ransack works for show action but not for when I render 'search_city'

Comment: assign the params first and only then you can use the redirect or render in your method. Else before the objects are assigned, the page will be redirected or rendered, so the params below will not be available in view. I hope you got my point. The code if BoatGroup.friendly.find(params[:boat_group_id]).name == 'All'  put them first and then have the code for redirect or render.

Comment: Got it. that solves the problem, however rendering is not creating the urls I wanted to have. How can I create search/country/.. and search/country/city.. with only one action without infinite redirection

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148872/discussion-between-shalafisters-and-shabini-rajadas).